# Ogg Opus HTTP stream

Tags: c, audio-streaming, ogg, opus, internet-radio

I'm looking to implement a radio broadcasting server program.  I want to use the Opus Codec.  I tried looking at icecast source code, but it seems like they don't even depend on libopus, and I can't figure out how it could even work.  Basically, what I can't figure out how to do is a C example of an HTTP ogg opus stream server that a web browser would be able to play in an audio element.  I can't find any examples online for this.

Comment: Do you wish to both play and seek ogg opus? Seeking ogg is not exactly the easiest thing to do

Comment: No, just compress raw audio as ogg opus and send it to a web browser to be played.  So, I would have thought opus packet, wrap in ogg packet, wrap in http packet, then send, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Consider reaching out to the [Opus Mailing List](http://lists.xiph.org/mailman/listinfo/opus). Try to find an example that already uses a non-Opus encoder and then work towards swapping out the encoder to Opus